# breaking outer template rule and create new rule for decedents

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have situation where I have to brake the the XSLT flow to wrap the certain tags (with attribute) into a another tags. let me explain:
Currently in my XSLT (below) the outer topic tags starts a wrapper `pagesequence` element. I want to break outer `pagesequence` tag when encounter `<p ouputclass=special>`, and fit in new `pagesequence`.

Input:

```
<root>
<topic>
    <p>Outertopic1Para1</p>
    <p>Outertopic1Para2</p>
</topic>
<topic>
    <p>Outertopic2Para1</p>
    <p>Outertopic2Para2</p>
</topic>
<topic>
    <p>Outertopic3Para1</p>
    <p>Outertopic3Para2</p>
    <topic>
        <p outputclass="special">specialPara3</p>
        <p>Innertopic1Para4</p>           
    </topic>
</topic>
<topic>
    <p>Outertopic4Para1</p>
    <p>Outertopic4Para2</p>
    <topic>
        <p outputclass="special">specialPara3</p>
        <p>Innertopic1Para4</p>
    </topic>
</topic>
</root>
```

Output Expected:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="portrait">
            <foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic1Para1</p>
                </foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic1Para2</p>
                </foblock>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="portrait">
            <foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic2Para1</p>
                </foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic2Para2</p>
                </foblock>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="portrait">
            <foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic3Para1</p>
                </foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic3Para2</p>
                </foblock>
                <foblock> </foblock>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence marster-refrence="special">
            <foblock>
                <p outputclass="special">specialPara3</p>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence>
            <foblock>
                <p>Innertopic1Para4</p>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="portrait">
            <foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic4Para1</p>
                </foblock>
                <foblock>
                    <p>Outertopic4Para2</p>
                </foblock>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence marster-refrence="special">
            <foblock>
                <p outputclass="special">specialPara3</p>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
        <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="portrait">
            <foblock>
                <p>Innertopic1Para4</p>
            </foblock>
        </page-sequence>
    </root>
```

Sample XSLT, I tried to create test xslt here, but is it possible to achieve this on top of below code, in that way I dont have to tweak the rest of DITA-OT flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topic">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::topic">
            <foblock>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </foblock>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="potrait">
                <foblock>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </foblock>
            </page-sequence>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <foblock>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </foblock>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `xsl:otherwise` could be changed to only select non-`topic` nodes, and then have a separate select of `topic` statements after the creation of the block

```
<xsl:otherwise>
   <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="potrait">
      <foblock>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except topic"/>
      </foblock>
   </page-sequence>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="topic"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

You would then need a separate template to handle `p` elements within a descendant `topic` element

```
<xsl:template match="topic[ancestor::topic]/p">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topic">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::topic">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <page-sequence page="pageNum()" marster-refrence="potrait">
                <foblock>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except topic"/>
                </foblock>
            </page-sequence>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="topic"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <foblock>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </foblock>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topic[ancestor::topic]/p">
    <page-sequence>
        <xsl:if test="@outputclass='special'">
            <xsl:attribute name="marster-refrence" select="'special'" />
        </xsl:if>
        <foblock>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </foblock>
    </page-sequence>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is good but it wraps all the child topics into separate pagesequence tag. it should only do when encounter @outputclass=special. And also the topics can have multiple levels. Sorry if was not clear in my original post.